# Solving a linear system of four equations and not getting a unique solution

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, systems-of-equations

Below is a problem I did. I believe my answer is right but I am not sure. Also, is my notation right?

Problem:
Solve the following system of equations:
\begin{align*}
w + x + y - z &= 1 \\
2w + x + y + z &= 8 \\
2w + x + y - 3z &= -4 \\
w + x + y + z &= 7
\end{align*}

Answer:

To solve these equations, I setup a matrix with a slight change in the order
of the equations to make the computation easier.
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 7 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 8 \\
2 & 1 & 1 & -3 & -4 \\
\end{bmatrix} $$
Now we apply row operations to simplify the matrix.
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 7 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 8 \\
2 & 1 & 1 & -3 & -4 \\
\end{bmatrix} &\sim
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 7 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -2 & -6 \\
0 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -6 \\
2 & 1 & 1 & -3 & -4 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 7 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 8 \\
2 & 1 & 1 & -3 & -4 \\
\end{bmatrix} &\sim
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 7 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\
0 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -6 \\
0 & -1 & -1 & -5 & -18 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 7 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 8 \\
2 & 1 & 1 & -3 & -4 \\
\end{bmatrix} &\sim
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 7 \\
0 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -6 \\
0 & -1 & -1 & -5 & -18 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}  &\sim
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 7 \\
0 & -1 & -1 & 0 & -3 \\
0 & -1 & -1 & -5 & -18 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 7 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 8 \\
2 & 1 & 1 & -3 & -4 \\
\end{bmatrix} &\sim
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 7 \\
0 & -1 & -1 & 0 & -3 \\
0 & -1 & -1 & 0 & -3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\end{align*}
At this point we know that $z = 3$ and that we are not going to have a unique solution.
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 7 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 8 \\
 2 & 1 & 1 & -3 & -4 \\
\end{bmatrix} &\sim
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 7 \\
 0 & -1 & -1 & 0 & -3 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 7 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 8 \\
 2 & 1 & 1 & -3 & -4 \\
\end{bmatrix} &\sim
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 4 \\
 0 & -1 & -1 & 0 & -3 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 7 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 8 \\
 2 & 1 & 1 & -3 & -4 \\
\end{bmatrix} &\sim
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 4 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\end{align*}
Now we have found $w = 1$. Now we work with the equation represented by the first row of the matrix.
\begin{align*}
w + x + y &= 4 \\
1 + x + y &= 4 \\
x + y &= 3 \\
x &= 3 - y\\
\end{align*}
Let $y_0$ be any arbitrary real number. Then the solution set for this system of
equations is:
$$ ( 1, 3 - y_0, y_0, 3 ) $$

Comment: Substituting $1$ for $w$, $3$ for $x+y$, and $3$ for $z$ seems to check.

Comment: Equivalently you could continue with row operations to get the reduced row echelon form:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 4 \\
 0 & -1 & -1 & 0 & -3 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\overset{R1+R2\to R1}\sim \cdots
\overset{-R2\to R2}\sim
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 3 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> System of equations:
> $$w + x + y - z = 1 \\
> 2w + x + y + z = 8 \\
> 2w + x + y - 3z = -4 \\
> w + x + y + z = 7$$

Your process is no doubt correct. But you can try this.

Solution:

$x+y=:v$

Now system of equations reduces:

$$w + v - z = 1 \\
2w + v + z = 8 \\
2w + v - 3z = -4 \\
w + v + z = 7$$

We can represent the system of linear equations in matrix form follows (without taking third equation):

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & -1 \\
2 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
w \\
v \\
z \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
8 \\
7 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Or,

$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
2 & 1 & 1 & 8 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 7 \\
\end{array}\right]
$$

Step 1: Subtract twice the first row from the second row and once the first row from the third row.

$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 3 & 6 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 6 \\
\end{array}\right]\sim\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 3 & 6 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\
\end{array}\right]
$$

Step 2: Add the second row to the first row.

$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 2 & 7 \\
0 & -1 & 3 & 6 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\
\end{array}\right]
$$

Step 3: Subtract three times the third row from the second row and subtract twice third row from the first row.

$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & -3 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\
\end{array}\right]
$$

Now, we can read the solutions for the variables:

$$w = 1\\
v = 3\\
z = 3\\$$

Check solution for third equation: $2w + v - 3z = 2+3-9=-4$ satisfy the third equation.

Now, $v=x+y=3$. Hence, there is infinitely many solution for $x,y$.